# Exception after Setting property 'spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars' in 'spark-defaults.conf'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Given below is the version of Spark & Hive I have installed in my system

**Spark**  : `spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6`

**Hive**   : `apache-hive-1.0.0-bin`

I have configured the Hive installation to use **MySQL** as Metastore. The goal is to access the **MySQL** Metastore & execute HiveQL queries inside `spark-shell`(using `HiveContext`)

So far I am able to execute the HiveQL queries by accessing the Derby Metastore(As described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interacting-with-different-versions-of-hive-metastore), believe **Spark-1.4** comes bundled with **Hive 0.13.1** which in turn uses the internal Derby database as Metastore)

Then I tried to point `spark-shell` to my external Metastore(MySQL in this case) by setting the property(as suggested [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interacting-with-different-versions-of-hive-metastore)) given below in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`,

```
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars   /home/mountain/hv/lib:/home/mountain/hp/lib
```

I have also copied `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml` into `$SPARK_HOME/conf`. But I am getting the following exception when I start the `spark-shell`

```
    mountain@mountain:~/del$ spark-shell 
    Spark context available as sc.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState when creating Hive client 
using classpath: file:/home/mountain/hv/lib/, file:/home/mountain/hp/lib/
    Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are 
included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.
```

Am I missing something (or) not setting the property `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars` correctly?

Comment: Try appending a trailing `/*` to the path as in - https://docs.databricks.com/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore.html

Answer (score 0):

Note: **In Linux Mint verified.**

If you are setting properties in spark-defaults.conf, spark will take those settings only when you submit your job using spark-submit.

file: **spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions      -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=app-logs -Dlogfile.name=hello-spark
spark.jars.packages                 org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.0.1
```

In the terminal run your job say wordcount.py

```
spark-submit /path-to-file/wordcount.py
```

If you want to run your job in development mode from an IDE then you should use config() method. Here we will set Kafka jar packages

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('Hello Spark') \
    .master('local[3]') \
    .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: For more details checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862801/spark-shell-add-multiple-drivers-jars-to-classpath-using-spark-defaults-conf/65799134#65799134

Answer (score -1):

Corrupted version of hive-site.xml will cause this... please copy the correct hive-site.xml